# How is github so fast?

Tags: page-speed

When you browse repositories on github ( for example https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/tree/master/bin) it feels like it uses ajax and does not reload the whole page every time. However the url really changes (not just after the # ).

I already found this article where they write about their backend: https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast

But is this really the whole trick?

My pages never feel that fast and I am already using yslow to optimize it.

Comment: Not so fast in IE8 it seems, which I assume does not support this HTML5 feature. In IE8, when the URL changes the entire page appears to be refereshed.

Comment: @w3d I think GitHub is either assuming that you're progressive enough to use something other than IE if you're using git. They may also just have decided not to support IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL change is a mix of an old feature of HTML when calling an A tag with hashes,

```
<a href="#home">Go to my home</a>
<p>TextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
<a id="home">
```

that makes possible linking parts of the same page without reloading at all,
and a new HTML5 JavaScript window object

```
window.onhashchange
```

This new object it's a event handler, that fires when a link with hashes is clicked, so it's possible to handle that event with JavaScript and possibiliting browser history and back buttons.
Here's a exemple

```
function hashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#home") {
        showPage('home');
    }
}

window.onhashchange = hashChanged;
```

[Mozzila Developer Network window.onhashchange Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange)

[jQuery hashchange event cross-browser plug-in](http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/tree/v1.3)

Comment: But github has no hash in the url. How is this done?

Comment: ok, found it: http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page